# Apply CSS based on text length of <a href="">

Tags: jquery

If a href is longer than 40 chars I want apply a class to the previous LI element.

How can I do this in jQuery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('li a').filter(function () {
    return $(this).attr('href').length > 40;
}).closest('li').addClass(...);
```

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/BPQBe/1

Further reading:

- [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

Comment: You don't need to use the `each` method, you can directly work on the result set from the `filter` call (I've updated my jsfiddle demo with an example).